# Designing a Database for a PHP system which can handle time-table of a institute and can manage marking and checking previous attendance

Tags: php, mysql, database, web-applications, rdbms

I am trying  to make a PHP-MySQL application for school system management. It should be able to handle the time table of entire week. Faculty, student can check their respective time tables. Faculty should be able to mark attendance of students of every lecture and should be able to modify previous attendance also. A faculty should be able to check attendance of individual days.
But, I am very confused regarding designing a database for such scenerio. What should be the ideal design ???

Comment: This is too broad a question for stackoverflow. It may require some hours of careful thought, more than an answer would take. We cannot also possibly take into account all the requirements which undoubtedly exist or will come to light, but have not been stated here. If you would like our help, you need to start to come up with a design yourself and ask us if you have a more specific question about one problematic area of it.

Comment: P.s. read https://stackoverflow.com/tour and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, please